# jQuery animate not smooth

Tags: jquery, wordpress, animation

I have wordpress website here http://www.itmc.lt/naujas/ and I made my header background to be slider with this jQuery script. The only problem is that in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M2LmH/245/ all transitions look smooth, while on my website there is no transition, just instant flash and image change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var img_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    newIndex = 0,
    index = 0,
    interval = 8000;
(function changeBg() {
    //  --------------------------
    //  For random image rotation:
    //  --------------------------
    //  newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % img_array.length;
    //  index = (newIndex === index) ? newIndex -1 : newIndex;
    //  ------------------------------
    //  For sequential image rotation:
    //  ------------------------------
    index = (index + 1) % img_array.length;
    $('#branding').css('backgroundImage', function () {
        $('#branding').animate({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }, 2000, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#branding').animate({
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
                }, 2000);
            }, 4000);
        });
        return 'url(http://placekitten.com/150/15' + img_array[index] +')';
    });
    setTimeout(changeBg, interval);
})();
});
```

Comment: You have `jQuery is not defined` error in `console`!!

Comment: try increasing the timer delay value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to user jQuery.

Add this lines at the end of **functions.php** file:

```
function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have inserted this function, but still animations doesn't look smooth

Comment: But, in JSFiddle, thats work correctly. Try changing the jQuery version (***1.8.1*** to ***1.9.1***)

Answer (score 1):

Check your console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

You must include jQuery in order to achieve the animations

Add this to your head section:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in the header.php file

```
 <?php
         wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 ?>
```

Also in your header file the  jquery script is not properly imported.
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not defined in your console. Include the jQuery in your head section.